# Can a Mac be powered on from a peripheral device in a mechanical off state (g3 state)

Tags: mac, power-management

Wake on lan works if the power has never been cut to the mac while it was off (G2 state), but is there any method by which to power on a mac mini from USB,ethernet, etc with out physically pushing the power button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do this.

I have been working with disabled Mac users who are physically unable to push a regular power button and trying to find a solution to this problem for a long time, with no luck.

Comment: I've looked into this heavily and you are right htere is no way to do it.
Thanks